# On click of radio button i have to make datatable row selectable and unselectable in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi i need to make my data table row selectable and unselectable based upon the radio button selection . There is two radio button above the data table one for making all table row unselectable as well as a button `Continue` invisible and other for making all row selectable as well as button `Continue` visible please tell me the way

```
<p:dialog id="duplicatePatientDlgId" header="Duplicate Patients"
            resizable="false" widgetVar="duplicatePatientDlg" modal="true"
            height="362" width="502" styleClass="popupheader"
            closeOnEscape="true">
            <div style="margin: 5px;">
                <div class="commonContainer" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <div class="Quick-ebill-SubHeader-01">Possible Duplicates
                        Found</div>
                    <div class="Duplicate-Patient-Dialogstyle">
                        <h5 style="margin-top: 3px;">At least one possible match
                            for this patient was found in your database.</h5>
                        <h5>Please select:</h5>
                        <div id="duplicatePatientRadioButtonPanel">
                            <h:selectOneRadio id="selectRadio" value="true" tabindex="1">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Create new patient record"></f:selectItem>
                                <f:selectItem
                                    itemLabel="Create Quick eBill for existing patient">
                                    <p:ajax event=""></p:ajax>
                                </f:selectItem>
                            </h:selectOneRadio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p:panel styleClass="popuppanel01">
                    <p:spacer height="10"></p:spacer>
                    <p:dataTable var="duplicatePatient" id="dupTable"
                        value="#{quickBillNewPatient.duplicateList}" scrollable="true"
                        scrollHeight="130">
                        <p:column headerText="Name" width="150">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{duplicatePatient.firstname}  #{duplicatePatient.lastname}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Date of Birth" width="150">
                            <h:outputText value="#{duplicatePatient.dateOfBirth}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column rendered="#{quickBillNewPatient.defaultLabel}"
                            headerText="#{quickBillNewPatient.defaultIdentifierLabel}">

                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
                <div styleClass="Header_Inner_commonContainer">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="buttonpopup floatLeft">
                        <span> <p:commandButton id="continueSave"
                                value="Continue Save"
                                actionListener="#{quickBillNewPatient.savePatient(false)}"
                                oncomplete="duplicatePatientDlg.hide()" />
                        </span>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>
            </div>

        </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean property to your backing bean an in listener of radio buttons just switch it to `true/false` and add attributte disabledSelection which will have a value from your bean boolean property. And by clicking on radio button you should update `datatable` `dupTable`

Comment: Thanks for replying but attribute disableSelection is not working please tell me the other way if u know

Comment: Which version of primefaces do you use?